# Git diff between two commits without some commits in the middle

Tags: git, git-diff

I have a git log like:

```
commit: abasued1..
commit: jsdiq7di..
commit: 2348fbvb..
commit: 0123ruhw..
commit: 9chvef87..
commit: 834rhbf3..
```

I want a diff of changes between commits `834rhbf3..` and `abasued1..` without the commits `0123ruhw..` and `2348fbvb..` included in it.

I know how to get the entire diff between the two commits, but is there a way to exclude certain commits from a range?

Comment: What do you mean you want to exclude certain commits? If you compare two commits, you are comparing the *snapshots* from that exact time. How would excluding particular commits work?

Comment: I need the diff to show all the changes over time

Comment: That doesn’t really answer my question… But `git diff commit1 commit2` will show a diff showing *everything* that has happened since `commit1` to get to `commit2`. Is that not what you want?

Comment: `git diff` is always [well *almost* always, or at least "usually"] pairwise: you diff "tree as stored under commit X" vs "tree as stored under commit Y".  Thus, as others noted, you must "undo" intermediate commits to do a pairwise commit minus those intermediates.  [*almost* The main exception is when looking at a merge, when git will offer you a "combined diff".]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a diff containing the changes between two points in time, except for changes that occurred as part of a certain two commits.

I don't believe there's a way to do it with a single command; git simply wouldn't be able to construct a meaningful diff if any of your later changes depended on the excluded commits.

If you want to give this a shot without modifying your branch, you can do three separate diffs:

```
git diff 834rhbf3 9chvef87   # changes made in 9chvef87
git diff 2348fbvb jsdiq7di   # changes made in jsdiq7di
git diff jsdiq7di abasued1   # changes made in abasued1
```

Note that, if changes in `abasued1` or `jsdiq7di` build on changes in the two excluded commits, you will still see portions of them as context.

Answer (score 3):

I think I finally understand you. you can use this.
`$ git revert --no-edit 2348fbvb
$ git revert --no-edit 0123ruhw
$ git diff 834rhbf3 HEAD`

---

**ORIGINAL POST**

Maybe I misunderstood you, but have you tried `git diff 834rhbf3 abasued1`? see [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html).

Answer (score 0):

**An indirect way but serves the purpose:**

1. Create Branch B1 with all the existing commits.
2. Create Branch B2 with commits you want to keep.

Now, do a diff for the two branches as follows:

```
git diff B1..B2
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's an unconventional and brute force approach.

First, for safety, make a copy of the entire project at the root where the .git directory is.

Now, using this *copy*...

Use the interactive rebase process, e.g. `git rebase -i HEAD~10`

and actually delete the commits you don't want (by deleting the entire lines that represents those commits) and save your work.

Then you'll be able to do the `git diff` of commitA to commitB without the commits between.

Then delete this directory (`rm -r`) so you don't accidentally push it anywhere!

Comment: It’s *incredibly likely* that by doing that, you end up with heavy merge conflicts due to missing states in between because rebase works by applying patches. (Also, a separate branch would be enough to do this crazy thing; no need to copy the whole repository…)

Comment: No need to back up the whole repo first, just do a `git checkout -b temp_branch abasued1` and do the interactive rebase on that branch.