# Compare changes from a set of commits to a prior version

Tags: git

I have a branch with commit `A` with a version of an application with verified working state. Than there are `N` commits that applied some potentially irrelevant/breaking changes. Followed by `M` commits which purpose was to implement some feature, but other potentially irrelevant/breaking changes were introduced. I need to select and apply changes that are only relevant to introduced feature and get rid of those that are irrelevant/potentially breaking.
So, it looks like:
`A -> N... -> M... -> P...`.
How can I compare changes from **a set of** `M..` to `A`?

---

Similar question: [Git diff between two commits without some commits in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548604/git-diff-between-two-commits-without-some-commits-in-the-middle/22548688)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to create a branch, which starts from `A`, and contains only commits of the `M...` range.

You can do this using `git rebase -i` :

```
# create a new branch from your current branch :
git checkout -b feature

# run :
git rebase -i <A>

# an editor opens : the instructions on what to do with this file are
# explained as comments at the bottom of the file

# in your case : remove all lines mentioning commits in
# the 'N...' and 'P...' ranges

# save and exit
```

You may have to fix conflicts along the way, but the end result should be : a new branch, with a copy of all `M...` commits on top of `A`.

Comparing commits from this branch against `A` will be more straightforward.

---

Actually, you can have `git rebase` select the range of commits `M...` range of commits :

- spot `<lastN>`, the hash of the *parent* of the first commit in `M...`,
- spot `<lastM>`, the hash of the last commit in `M...`
- run the following commands :

```
git branch feature <lastM>
git rebase --onto <A> <lastN> feature
```

You can add `-i` to the `git rebase` command, if you want to confirm that you selected all the commits you expect.

---

Cherry-picking each commit in `M...` on top of `<A>`, as you suggested in your comment, is also a valid way to create that branch :

```
# to list the commits :
git rev-list <lastN>..<lastM>

# to use it in a cherry-pick command :
git checkout -b feature <A>  # start from <A>
git cherry-pick $(git rev-list <lastN>..<lastM>)
```

---

All three ways will give the same result.

Comment: If you have too many conflicts to handle in the middle of your rebase, know that `git rebase --abort` will restore your repo to its state prior to the rebase.

Comment: Can I maybe create a branch from `A` and cherry-pick each of `M...`?

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik : yes, you can also do that. Updated my answer.